# Check if string equals asterisk in Bash scripting?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I'm making a bash script to do basic arthmetic and when I do:

```
if [ $2 == "*" ]
```

it does not work.

How can I check for asterisk?

Comment: Unix Philosophy 102: Let the shell do what the shell does best, and use `bc` or `dc` if you want a calculator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape or quote the asterisk in the command line:

```
./calculator.sh 2 \* 2
./calculator.sh 2 '*' 2
```

and enclose the `$2` in double quotes:

```
if [ "$2" == "*" ]
```

Comment: Oh good. For a moment I thought I'd need to beat someone over the head with the BASH FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't that the `if` statement isn't working, it is that the asterisk on the command line is being [globbed](http://www.faqs.org/docs/abs/HTML/globbingref.html).

So if your script was called `mycalc` and run from the command line you do

```
mycalc 2 * 3
```

The `*` will get globbed, and converted to all the names of the files in the current folder.

To avoid expansion, you would need to do

```
mycalc 2 \* 3
```

The `\` escapes the asterisk and passes it through without changing it.

You might want to consider `x` for the multiplication operation to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Find ASCII value of `*` by using the command below

```
printf "%d\n" "'`echo "*" | awk '{print $1}'`"
```

and use that value for condition checking.

Comment: Unfortunately you do not say how to use the ASCII value for the condition checking.